# CSS auto Height in every div

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck in styling the DIV height in my page.

Example :

```
<div class="container_post">
<div class="delete_post">Delete</div>
 bla bla bla
</div>

<div class="container_post">
<div class="delete_post">Delete</div>
 bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla
</div>
```

We see for that 2 example have different height when it loaded. Now my question, how can I set `.delete_post` auto height in every div that have different height.

CSS

```
.delete_post
{
position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is "auto height" exactly?

Comment: Auto height, means depends on .container_post height.

Comment: not sure of what you wanted to do . div adjusting its height according to its contents is just the way it does.

Comment: why are you using position:absolute?? if u remove it,it will work fine